# Run device as simulator which is not in the USB Vendor IDs

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have a Best a Buy easy home 7 tablet 7 and I'd like to use it as simulator with eclipse.

I've update adb and and kill adb server and run it again.

I'm working in OSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

1. While the tablet was connected, I ran this in a terminal:

   ```
   system_profiler SPUSBDataType
   ```

   This yielded the following information about the tablet:

   ```
   BB:

       Product ID: 0x0010
       Vendor ID: 0x2207  (Fuzhou Rockchip Electronics Co., Ltd.)
   ```
2. I modified the `adb_usb.ini` file in `~/.android/`, adding my vendor ID to the end of the file as follows:

   ```
   # USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
   # 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
   0x2207
   ```
3. Finally the device appeared in Eclipse in the *Android Device Chooser*.

I hope someone else finds this useful.

Comment: It wasn't very difficult :)

Comment: @meda I think **xarly** must have chosen the "answer your own question" option, which is encouraged for Q/A style knowledge sharing. :)

Comment: That's it, I choose "answer you own question" to share the solution and the problem. Thanks @JordanGray